# Совместимость компиляторов MinGW и отладчиков GDB

Tags: c, codeblocks, gdb, mingw-w64

Я использую компиляторы `MinGW32`, `MinGW-w64 x32`, `MinGW-w64 x64` и поставляемые с этими компиляторами отладчики `GDB`. Работаю в `Windows 10 x64`.

С компилятором `MinGW32`, который идет в коробке с `Code::Blocks 17.12`, проблем нет. Компилятор работает стабильно. Его коробочный отладчик функционирует так же стабильно.

Но у меня возникают проблемы с коробочными отладчиками компиляторов `MinGW-w64 x32` и `MinGW-w64 x64`. Отладка, в принципе, запускается, и я даже могу получить ассемблерный листинг, посмотреть состояние переменных и пр. Но сам процесс отладки намертво зависает и отключить его возможно только через диспетчер задач.

Я не могу понять, с чем это связано. Сперва я думал, что отладка зависает из-за каких-то несовместимостей между используемыми отладчиками и самой средой `Code::Blocks`. Но потом оказалось, что если установить компиляторы более старых версий (2-3 версии назад), то коробочные отладчики более старых версий не зависают.

Я пытался использовать отладчики перекрестно, но это, очевидно, работать не будет.

Собственно, мои вопросы:

- Почему коробочные отладчики `GDB`, которые устанавливаются вместе с последними версиями `MinGW-w64`, зависают?
- Какова вообще природа совместимости отладчиков и компиляторов? Важна ли разрядность, версии и пр.?

PS. Почему-то в случайный момент времени при смене компилятора или отладчика, любые точки останова начинают игнорироваться, и я не могу найти способа, почему это происходит. Не помогает смена отладчика/компилятора, переименование проекта, очистка/перестройка рабочего места и проекта. Даже стандартный отладчик начинает игнорировать точки останова. А в списке отладчиков может появиться дополнительный пустой пункт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В консоли gdb из поставки MinGW-w64 x64 работает прекрасно. Стоит отправить разработчикам Code::Blocks багрепорт на эту тему.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, значит это точно связано с IDE? Я вот сейчас тестировал. Поставил `MinGW-w64 x64 v7.3`, его `GDB v8.1` при отладке зависает. Поставил `MinGW-w64 x64 v5.4`, его `GDB v7.10` работает нормально. И даже если я использую более новый `MinGW-w64 x64 v7.3` с более старым отладчиком `GDB v7.10`, то отладчик не зависает.

Comment: Возможно, самый последний `GDB` просто имеет какие-то тонкости, которые не учтены в `Code::Blocks 17.12`, так как IDE вышла год назад?

Comment: Возможно что то напутано с путями, и отладчик новой версии берет библиотеки от старой версии, которая возможно прописана где то в путях. С каробочным вариантом мингв-тдм была какая то пляска с бубном, пришлось переименовывать директории внутри мингв, там где зачем-то жили аналогичные gdb и make кажется.. уже точно не вспомню. Проверьте пути, и пропишите в пути только путь к папке mingw/bin новой версии. У меня gcc + gdb 8.1 и все нормально.

Comment: @NewView, в том-то и дело, что у меня сейчас имеется набор из трех компиляторов и трех отладчиков. Отладчики лежат в директориях соответствующих им компиляторов. Список отладчиков настраивается отдельно от компиляторов. И при этом проекту можно задавать конкретный компилятор, а так же конкретный отладчик. В самом `Code::Blocks` присутствуют какие-то странные баги. То при смене компилятора и отладчика начинают игнорироваться все точки останова, то в списке отладчиков появляется пустая строка. Сейчас пытаюсь методом тыка определить, что это за дела.

Comment: @МаксимГлухманюк У вас эти отладчики и из консоли не работают?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, из консоли работают.

Comment: 1 - `лежат в директориях соответствующих им компиляторов`, 2 -`Список отладчиков настраивается отдельно от компиляторов` : вероятно проблема в этом, он берет один тулчейн с прописанными путями, и запускает gdb с другими библиотеками, из загруженного тулчейна.

Comment: Поступите проще, физически перенесите все компиляторы от их корневой директории в недоступное по путям место (временно), оставьте только самый свежий. Если будет при запуске gdb ругаться на пути - значит оно.